# Batch or PHP Get Numbers within String in Arrax

Tags: php, arrays, string, batch-file, numbers

I'm looking for a solution to get all numbers within a string into an array, but maybe some numbers contain dots ".".

They are separated by either a space or a letter.

I tried it with cutting, explode and didn't even come close to a result. So basiclly I don't have any code to show.

And it doesn't really matter if it is in Batch or PHP.

Thanks a lot. Regards !

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: Show your attempts and also what the data looks like, otherwise nobody is going to bother helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular match to get these numbers as string, when you want trans them to number, use floatval or others.

```
preg_match_all('!\d+\.*\d*!', $string ,$matches);
array_map(function($v){return floatval($v);}, $matches);
```